# Return a default value of a hash

Tags: ruby, hash, default

I need help. I am doing a basic exercise in Ruby, but right now I don't understand defult that much.
I need to write a function called temp that reicive one argument (a hash). The function must return the same hash but with the next changes:

- If the hash doesn't have the key :puppy return 4 as value.
- If the hash doesn't have the key :cat return 6 as value.

Comment: You should edit your question to clarify, so the hold may be removed. Something like the following (my understanding) may be clearer:  "I wish to create a method `temp` that has one argument,  a hash `h`. The method must modify `h` in such a way that: `h[:puppy] #=>  4` if `h` does not have a key `:puppy` and `h[:cat] #=>  6` if `h` does not have a key `:cat`. Beyond that, `h` is to have the same key-value pairs as before.". I have assumed you want to mutate ("modify") the hash `h`, as opposed to returning a new hash with the desired properties. There's no need for the first two sentences.

Comment: "functions" in other languages are called "methods" in Ruby. In spelling "receive" the [rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_before_E_except_after_C) is: "I before E except after C, as opposed to I before and after C and no E".

Comment: Try this: `def temp(h); h.default_proc =  ->(h,k) { case k when :puppy then 4 when :cat then 6; else nil end }; h; end`. If `g = temp( a: 1, puppy: 'woof')`, then 
`g[:a] #=> 1;  g[:puppy] #=> "woof"; g[:cat] #=> 6`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this question is about default values, you're after either `default` or `default_proc`. You can make a new hash and give it a default proc via `Hash.new`.

```
def temp(h)
  Hash.new do |hash, key|
    if key == :puppy
      h.fetch(:puppy, 4)
    elsif key == :cat
      h.fetch(:cat, 6)
    else
      h[key]
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

While `Hash#default_proc` is the right way to go, both answers here are overcomplicated for this particular task. The following is probably what you actually need here.

```rb
def temp(h)
  h[:puppy] ||= 4
  h[:cat] ||= 6
  h
end
```

Comment: Thank you, Aleksei. I still don't know a lot of Ruby. ^^

Comment: This overwrites the previous values if they are nil or false. That is not the same behaviour as supplying a default. The question specifically says "if the hash does not have the key", which is not at all the behaviour of ||=.

Comment: Yeah, it would be more accurate to do `h[:puppy] = h.fetch(:puppy, 4)` etc.

Comment: @MarkReed or `h[:puppy] = 4 unless h.key?(:puppy)`, but this would be the next step. It’s better to learn step by step and people asking questions like this probably do not need all these details at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little confusing.

```
If the hash doesn't have the key :puppy return 4 as value.
If the hash doesn't have the key :cat return 6 as value.
```

I think you want a function that returns a version of the passed-in hash that defaults the keys `:puppy` and `:cat` to 4 and 6, respectively, assuming they aren't already in the passed-in hash. This should work:

```
def temp(source)
  return Hash.new do |h, k|
    case k 
      when :puppy then 4
      when :cat then 6
    end
  end.merge(source)
end
```

Here's how this works.

We're defining a method that takes as its one parameter a basis hash (which I called `source`).

When you create a hash with [`Hash.new`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-c-new) and pass in a block of code, that block becomes the hash's "default proc". It will be called whenever a key that is not present in the hash is looked up, and its return value will appear to be the value stored at that key. When such a lookup happens, the block is passed two arguments: the hash itself and the key being requested. Here, I named those `h` and `k`. In the body, we check to see if `k` is either `:puppy` or `:cat` and return the appropriate value (4 or 6) if so. (If `k` is not either of those values, the `case` statement will automatically return `nil`.)

That creates a hash with the right default proc, but the hash is empty. We then populate it by calling [`Hash#merge`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-merge) on it with the passed-in source hash as argument; that will copy all of the keys from `source` into the new hash. The `merge` method call conveniently returns the hash it was called on, so we just return that result to the caller of our method.

Examples:

```
irb(main):001:0> h1 = temp( { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 } )
=> {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}
irb(main):002:0> h1[:a]
=> 1
irb(main):003:0> h1[:d]
=> nil
irb(main):004:0> h1[:cat]
=> 6
irb(main):005:0> h1[:puppy]
=> 4

irb(main):006:0> h2 = temp( { a: 1, cat: :dog } )
=> {:a=>1, :cat=>:dog}
irb(main):007:0> h2[:a]
=> 1
irb(main):008:0> h2[:b]
=> nil
irb(main):009:0> h2[:cat]
=> :dog
irb(main):010:0> h2[:puppy]
=> 4
```